# How to refresh a row in ui-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to refresh just the row that's been edited in the ui-grid and not the whole table.

So my business case is that I edit a row in the grid, trigger a rest call and the I want to updated just that specific row from the grid.

on rest call success:

```
   $http.put(representation.getLink('reports').href, {
         changes: manualModifications,
         comment: comment
    }).success(function(updatedEntities) {
        for (var i = 0; i < updatedEntities.length; i++) {
           angular.forEach(controller.gridOptions.data, function(entity) {
                if (updatedEntities[i].factId === entity.factId) {
                    entity.value = updatedEntities[i].value;
                    entity.dataOrigin = updatedEntities[i].dataOrigin;
                    entity.isDirty = false;
                }
           });
        }
        controller.gridApi.core.refresh();
   });
```

works as well using:

```
controller.gridApi.core.refreshRows();
```

this updating only the rows inside the grid, but still refreshes all the rows.

I have looked over the grid [api](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi) but I could not find something that does this.

I am thinking that since I have a reference to a grid row inside the forEach cycle should be possible to update just that single row.

Comment: In your posted code, you aren't even using the `data` variable being returned from your PUT and what is `updatedEntities`? You don't have enough posted to give an answer that isn't just a guess.

Comment: updatedEntities is the response/data returned from the backend, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you are doing the REST call (using JQuery, XHR directly, etc), you may need to call `$scope.$digest()` to get it back angularized in the digest cycle.

Comment: I have added the way I do the rest call

Comment: @aurelius that should be fine and not need the added digest call. please post a [mcve]

Comment: my solution works, and the coded that I posted is related to this possible improvement, only to update the rows which are returned from the rest response and not all the grid rows.